# Why does this android media player start after a long delay in Xamarin C#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to make android media player. It runs without any errors or bugs but it takes a lot of time to start.

This my code:

```
var item = items[position];

MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Reset();
player.SetDataSource(item.filePath);
player.Prepare();

button.Click += delegate
{

    if (!player.IsPlaying)
    {
        button.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.pauseicon);

        player.Start();
    }
    else if(player.IsPlaying)
    {
        button.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.starticonn);
        player.Pause();
    }
};
```

Comment: In emulator or real device?

Comment: Your if/else got edited (to a much better state)... can you update your code to match the state that it currently is in here in this question and see if that helps ?

Comment: real device samsung s6 edge plus

Comment: What is a "long delay"? What is the size of the file you are loading?